# Codeigniter assign another value instead of Null when reading GET/POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter,

```
$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;
```

is equal to

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');
```

Is there something like  `$something = $this->input->post('something','do');` in Codeigniter?

What I need is if there is not set post value I need assign another value instead of Null?

Comment: No, there is no built in functionality. The duplicate linked above shows you how to add the functionality via a derived class. The second answer is cleaner than the accepted one.

Comment: If you need only one time do something like that, why you do not : 
`if(!$something = $this->input->post('something'))
 $something = 'your_value';`

Comment: If your environment is PHP7 you can use [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php): `$something = $this->input->post('something') ?? 'do';`.